# Chain new Class() and function to the same variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, expression, new-operator

By creating a new instance of someClass() and chaining a function to the same variable, will a new someClass be created every time I call someFunc()?

```
const someFunc = new someClass().getOrSetOrWhatever()
```

compared to if I write it as is usually done

```
let s = new someClass()
s.getOrSetOrWhatever()
```

And if I put the first example into a constructor, would it mean that there would be only one instance (everytime I called this.someFunc)? Would it be bad practice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "*every time I call someFunc()?*" - does `getOrSetOrWhatever()` really return a function? Please show its code. In the code you've shown, there is no `function` expression!

Comment: Why would a new instance be created when you call `someFunc`? The line with `new someClass()` has already been executed, and is not *inside* the body of the function...

Comment: With what you suggest in the last paragraph, do you mean that the *constructor* would need to be called repeatedly? In that case, you *would* need to create an instance for each time you want the constructor to run.

Comment: Is .getOrSetOrWhatever a method that is on the prototype?  If so, you do not need to create a new instance at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `new someClass()` a new instance of someClass is created.  The "new" keyword causes a unique "copy" of the class to generate an new, unique copy (instance).

When you execute `getOrSetOrWhatever()` chained to `new someClass()` as:

```
let s = new someClass().getOrSetOrWhatever()
```

Then the "s" variable will contain the result of getOrSetOrWhatever (whatever that function returns).

**HOWEVER**, the instance that `new someClass()` generated will exist, but **not be accessible** because it was never assigned to a variable (potential memory leak) -- only the result of getOrSetOrWhatever is returned.

Chaining passes whatever is generated/returned on the left to the right.

```
foo().bar() 
// is like:
// foo() --> bar()
// or
// the method "bar" is within "foo"
```

When you don't chain as in:

```
let s = new someClass();
let foo = s.getOrSetOrWhatever();
```

Then the instance is assigned to the `s` variable and `foo` is assigned to whatever "getOrSetOrWhatever" returns.

Comment: Thank you bob, this was exactly what I wanted to know! Thanks for answering my question!

Answer (score 0):

if you write this like:

```
const someFunc = new someClass().getOrSetOrWhatever;
```

than someFunc will be reference (pointer) to method (function) of that instance of someClass, after if you call:

```
const someFunc = new someClass().getOrSetOrWhatever;    
someFunc();
...
someFunc();
```

is same as:

```
let s = new someClass()
s.getOrSetOrWhatever()
..
s.getOrSetOrWhatever()
```

Comment: This is similar but not always the same.

Comment: Only if getOrSetOrWhatever is muatable and changed between calls. In Javascript nothing can be same and everything could be same.

Comment: This is not what the OP is doing. His code does `someFunc = ….getOrSetOrWhatever()`.

Answer (score 0):

No, a new instance will not be created every time because the code "new someClass()" will not be called again

You have declared a variable named "someFunc".

The right side of your code is going to be evaluated, in order to assign a value to "someFunc"

When the right side of your code is read, it will first create a new instance.  If you did not have any more code on the right side, it would simply store that new instance to the variable.

But, since you are then calling a method called "getOrSetWhatever", the result of "getOrSetWhatever" will be stored to your variable.

Your instance is now just floating in memory somewhere and is not stored to any variable.

You have created an instance, invoked a method (that is either stored on that instance or stored on the class's prototype object), and stored the result of that method into your variable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205645/discussion-on-answer-by-maiya-chain-new-class-and-function-to-the-same-variabl).

Answer (score 0):

`someFunc` is just a variable here.

`new someClass()` would get called every time if you wrote `someFunc` as

`const someFunc = () => new someClass().getOrSetWhatever()`